# How can I use my own monorepos as package.json dependencies directly from github?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, monorepo

I am heavily using github directly (i.e. not using the npm registry) for my own reusable node modules. So what I do in my package.json (I use yarn classic) is this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-module": "https://github.com/username/my-module.git#v0.0.12",
},
```

How would I now handle this module if it was a monorepo consisting of several packages e.g. server and client?

Had I registered **my-module** with npm I would go about and do something like

```
"dependencies": {
    "@my-module/client": "0.0.12",
},
```

but how would I achieve the same result by directly addressing the github repository?

I've tried

```
"dependencies": {
  "@my-module/package-one": "https://github.com/username/my-module.git#v0.0.12",
},
```

and it did not work. I guess @module/package is an npm/yarn-registry convention, which is not understood by the yarn client.

I've also tried

```
"dependencies": {
  "package-one": "https://github.com/username/my-module.git/package-one#v0.0.12",
},
```

Didn't work either.

Can I do that at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out "yarn workspaces"? https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

I'm sure you could solve it with that feature in a monorepo setup. After you're pointing yarn to the folder(s) where your packages are located in the monorepo, it will just symlink them locally into the node_modules folder.

I guess you don't even need to point your dependencies to github directly anymore in a monorepo, because when you are in the monorepo, everything is handled by yarn workspaces and nothing needs to be published anywhere.

If you still want to publish your packages in the monorepo, go with a CI like "github actions" and let your build-publish-script run from there whenever you merge something to master/main

Comment: Of course the monorepos are setup as yarn workspaces. That's not the problem. I want to use each workspace as a single dependency in remote applications.

Besides using the monorepos locally (which is not the problem BTW, I got that working smoothely) I need to provide them for my co-workers as standalone modules. Therefore they need to be able to fetch the packages/workspaces each one as single depdendency from github. Like you would with any other dependency hosted on github.

I

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it (partly) going, by dropping the protocol path in the github url:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@my-module/package-one": "/username/my-module.git#v0.0.12",
},
```

Yarn's default git server location is github anyway. Don't know though, if checks if you want https or ssh access. I'm using an ssh key it worked instantly.

But, I have to hold my horses here.

Now I have the problem, that the location of package-one content is located at

```
node_modules/@my-module/package-one/packages/package-one
```

i.e. the project root, which is supposed to be at

```
node_modules/@my-module
```

is now located at

```
node_modules/@my-module/package-one
```

I apologize for the confusing explanation. I wish I could describe this in a better way.